# cookie is not working

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I set cookie in php by sending values through post but on redirect cookie, it showing that cookie is not set.

```
//username is just stored here for an example, it is not a good process to store credentials in cookie.

$('.loginDialogBtn').click(function() {
    $usernameLogIn = $('#usernameLogIn').val();
    var $passwordLogIn = $('#passwordLogIn').val();
    $.post('authorizationAdmin.php', {
        usernameLogIn: $usernameLogIn,
        passwordLogIn: $passwordLogIn
    }, function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        if (response['done'] ===  $usernameLogIn ) {
            location.href = 'http://foodinger.in/Admin/home.php?restUsername=' + $usernameLogIn;
        }
       else {
            $('.loginError').html('Incorrect Username and password');
        }
    });
});
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['usernameLogIn']) && !empty($_POST['usernameLogIn']) && isset($_POST['passwordLogIn']) && !empty($_POST['passwordLogIn'])) {
    $Username=strip_tags(trim($_POST['usernameLogIn'])); 
    $password = strip_tags(trim($_POST['passwordLogIn']));
    setcookie('username',$username, time() + (83600*30), "/Admin/", '.foodinger.in');
    setcookie('restaurantId',$restId, time() + (83600*30), "/Admin/", '.foodinger.in');
}
```

after click on login button i can see cookie is being set in my browser but i can't fetch it using $_COOKIE.

is there any server setting which could make it wrong ?

> **update** -- i was using "walkme" which created the problem, once i removed walkme and deleted all the cookies, it worked. Can anyone please
>   tell me why "walkme" is creating problem in fetching my cookie
>   variables

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you try like this: echo $_COOKIE['username'];    ??

Comment: yes i am using $_COOKIE['restaurantId'], but it is not set

Comment: check domain and path for dots and slashes, To read a cookie, those variables have to be exact the same as when you write the cookie. Your php file also has to be in the same folder as where the cookie is pointing to. Fr debugging purposes, remove path and domain and see if you can get the cookie then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to debug your cookie :

```
// Print an individual cookie
echo $_COOKIE["username"];
echo $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["username"];

// Another way to debug/test is to view all cookies
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: print_r($_COOKIE) is just printing Array ( )

Comment: It means that you're not set it before. try a simple setcookie first like `setcookie("username", $username, time()+3600);`